# How to make available in a usercontrol a inner control collection in Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, user-controls

I have a WPF `UserControl` wrapping some other controls. One of these is an `ItemsControl` and I need to make available in my `UserControl` the `Items` property of the `ItemsControl` so I did the following:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey PagesPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Pages", typeof(ObservableCollection<XXX>), typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<XXX>()));

    public static DependencyProperty PagesProperty = PagesPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public ObservableCollection<XXX> Pages
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<XXX>) base.GetValue(PagesProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(PagesProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then in the XAML the `ItemsControl` has the following:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Pages, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:TypeExtension views1:MyControl}}}"
```

I thought this should work and in fact looking with Snoop the `UserControl` and the `ItemsControl` have the same elements but when I add directly elements to the inner `ItemsControl` the first element I add gets automatically selected and when I do it using my `UserControl` no selection happens so something is wrong.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** The control is a Wizard control and as we use it always with some other controls around I am creating a new Usercontrol. If I use directly the Wizard in a View the first item of the ItemsSource gest automatically selected, if I set the ItemsSource of the Wizard to the Pages property then there is no selected page on startup.

I really wonder why this happens.

Comment: you can choose to derive from `ItemsControl` instead of just `UserControl`

Comment: @Vignesh.N: I have several controls to show that are not part of the ItemsControl. The ItemsControl will try to draw everything like a ListBox, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it replacing the ItemsSource binding with a constructor call:

```
this.ItemsControlInnerControl.ItemsSource = this.Pages;
```

No idea why this works and the binding does not ... anyway ...

Answer (score 1):

if your custom control is just going to be a `ItemsControl` you can derive from ItemsControl instead of `UserControl`

Also you don't see the item being selected when using your `UserControl` because when the binding happens during initialization the default value is an empty collection/`null` so the `SelectedItem` is `null` during initialization of the control.
Later once the `Pages` property has got its values you need to set `SelectedItem` of your `UserControl`

The `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` has another constructor where you specify the `PropretyChangedEventHandler` where you can set `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex`

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey PagesPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Pages", typeof(ObservableCollection<XXX>), typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,OnPagesChanged));

    public static DependencyProperty PagesProperty = PagesPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public ObservableCollection<XXX> Pages
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<XXX>) base.GetValue(PagesProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(PagesProperty, value); }
    }
}

        private static void OnPagesChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
//play with DepedencyObject here; cast it to type MyControl and assign/change instance variables
//Raise some events which can be bubbled.
//Set SelectedIndex here
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that but the real question is why the behavior changes ... ¿?

Comment: do you also have a `SelectedItem` property for your controls ? A `ItemsControl` would have a `SelectedItem` property and whenever the `ItemsSource` changes the control changes the `SelectedItem` (setting to the first one). Similarly you have `Pages` property and may be you need a `SelectedPage` and set it to a value which is not being done currently.